# c# foreach in a list with events

Tags: c#, list, event-handling

I'm having a problem using foreach in a list with events?

I think that the `foreach (NewPointEventArgs e in list)` is incorrect, could someone please help with the correct syntax for this line?

My code is as follows:

```
static  IList<NewPointEventArgs> list = new List<NewPointEventArgs>(); 

static void myNewPointRecorded(object sender, Kinect.NewPointEventArgs e)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Point Received: x={0}, y={1}, z={2}",e.X, e.Y, e.Z));

    list.Add(e);            
}


static void OnFrameEnded(object source, EventArgs e) 
{
}

foreach (NewPointEventArgs e  in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: Be more specific please. what do you want?

Comment: Hi and sorry for the trouble...foreach (NewPointEventArgs e  in list) is incorrect i want the correct syntax for this line.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use this foreach loop inside `OnFrameEnded` method
than you have used `e` twice. Try something like:

```
     static void OnFrameEnded(object source, EventArgs e) 
    {
        foreach (NewPointEventArgs element in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }

    }
```

Comment: No time to test but is NewPointEventArgs IEnumerable? Maybe make `foreach(EventArgs item in list) { NewPointEventArgs element = item as NewPointEventArgs; Console.WriteLine(element ?? String.Empty); }`
 Your answer is the correct answer probably.

Comment: `IList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Nvm im dumb haha, didn't see it was a list :p